# For Loop in Vacuum cleaner

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am writing a code about a vacuum cleaner that cleans dusts in a 2 dimensional array. I want this cleaner goes to the end of a row, then come back to complete the next row and so on. but in this code, it's goes to end of the first row and come back to begin of the first row again! What should I do? Thank you so much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int array[5][5];
    int step = 0 , trash, total = 0, num = 0;

    //Prepare the random array

    for (x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
        {

            array[x][y] = rand() % 2;

            if (array[x][y] == 1)
            {
               total++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Print the total number of trashes based on the random number

    cout<<endl<<"The total number of trashes are: "<<total<<endl<<endl;

    //print the random array

    for (x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<5; y++)
        {
            cout<<array[x][y]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    //------Manual Garbage Collector
    cout<<"------ Manual Garbage Collector ------"<<endl<<endl;

    while(num != total)
    {
        if(m % 2 != 0)
        {
            if(t==1)
                i=1;
            else if (t==3)
                i=3;

            for(i ; i<5 ; i++)
            {
                for(j=5 ; j>0 ; j--)
                {
                    trash = array[i][j];

                    if(trash == 1)
                    {
                        cout<<"I found a trash in   -->   "<<"row: "<<i<<"\t column: "<<j<<endl;
                        num++;
                        step++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        step++;
                    }
                }
            m++;
            t++;
            break;
            }
        }
        else if (m % 2 == 0)
        {
            if(t==2)
                i=2;
            else if (t==4)
                i=4;

            for(i ; i<5 ; i++)
            {
                for(j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
                {
                    trash=array[i][j];

                    if(trash == 1)
                    {
                        cout<<"I found a trash in   -->   "<<"row: "<<i<<"\t column: "<<j<<endl;
                        num++;
                        step++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        step++;
                    }

                }
            m++;
            t++;
            break;

            }
        }
    }

    cout<<endl<<"----------------"<<endl<<"The number of steps that I have tried: "<<step<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop over `i` never runs more than once. You excplicitly `break` out of it at the end of the first (and only) iteration; then enter it again with `i == 1`

Comment: I used several solutions to solve this problem, but I couldn't find the right answer. Could anyone help me what should I do? thanks.

Comment: Is anything unclear in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does actually go to the next row when it reaches the end of a row, but one problem is in your first j loop (line 65) because it goes out of bounds. It should be:

```
for( j = 4; j >= 0; j-- ) {
```

But the bigger problem is the whole logic that is weird and unnecessarily complicated. The same task can be completed with something simplier like this:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int direction[] = { 1, -1 };
int lower_limit[] = { 0, SIZE - 1 };
int count = 0;
int k = 0;

// for every row
for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
    // sweep the row in the right direction
    int j = lower_limit[k];
    for( int l = 0; l < SIZE; ++l ) {
        // clean the trash
        if ( array[i][j] ) {

            cout << "I found a trash in   -->   row: " << i
                 << "\t column: " << j << '\n';
            ++count;

            // I don't think it's worth checking now if all the dust were
            // collected, you'll save a few iterations but this condition
            // has to be checked for half of the cells at average
        }
        j += direction[k];
    }
    k = ( k == 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Or more similar to your code:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
int count = 0;
bool going_right = true;

// for every row
for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
    // sweep the row in the right direction
    if ( going_right ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j ) {
            // clean the trash
            if ( array[i][j] ) {
                cout << "I found a trash in   -->   row: " << i
                     << "\t column: " << j << '\n';
                ++count;
            }
        }
        // reverse direction
        going_right = false;
    }
    else {
        for( int j = SIZE - 1; j >= 0; --j ) {
            // clean the trash
            if ( array[i][j] ) {
                cout << "I found a trash in   -->   row: " << i
                    << "\t column: " << j << '\n';
                ++count;
            }
        }
        going_right = true;
    }
}
```

Which in your program gives this output:

```
The total number of trashes are: 16

1   0   1   0   0   
1   1   0   1   0   
1   1   0   1   1   
1   1   1   0   0   
0   1   1   1   1   


------ Manual Garbage Collector ------

I found a trash in   -->   row: 0    column: 0
I found a trash in   -->   row: 0    column: 2
I found a trash in   -->   row: 1    column: 3
I found a trash in   -->   row: 1    column: 1
I found a trash in   -->   row: 1    column: 0
I found a trash in   -->   row: 2    column: 0
I found a trash in   -->   row: 2    column: 1
I found a trash in   -->   row: 2    column: 3
I found a trash in   -->   row: 2    column: 4
I found a trash in   -->   row: 3    column: 2
I found a trash in   -->   row: 3    column: 1
I found a trash in   -->   row: 3    column: 0
I found a trash in   -->   row: 4    column: 1
I found a trash in   -->   row: 4    column: 2
I found a trash in   -->   row: 4    column: 3
I found a trash in   -->   row: 4    column: 4

----------------
The number of steps that I have tried: 25
```